# How to find positions of multiple characters in C#?

Tags: c#

For example I have a string "XXXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXX1XXXX0" I would like to get the position of any character that is not X and compare and see if those positions match in a different string. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

here is the code I am using

```
List<int> CharPositions = new List<int>();

    foreach(var character in stringValue)
                        {
                            if (character != "X"){
                                CharPositions .Add(stringValue.IndexOf(character));

                            }
                        }
```

My issue with my code is that I feel this is not the most efficient manner to do something like this. What would be a quicker way I guess is a better question?

Comment: and what have you ***tried yourself*** so far? what problems did you encounter? what did you research? SO is not a free code writing service, you know?

Comment: You might want to research Regular Expressions.

Comment: so, what was your approach? Did you try something on your own? if not, have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=net-5.0

Comment: usually one can use a loop to iterate over a string. A string is internally represented as a char array. So you can iterate over it and use the `[ ]` operator like this `char c = myString[i];` Actually this information should enable you to solve your entire problem. At least the part that you described to us

Comment: Sorry forgot to add my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stringValue.IndexOf(character)` will return the first index. Instead use a for loop and record the current index as below.

```
List<int> CharPositions = new List<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < stringValue.Length; i++)
{
     if (stringValue[i] != 'X')
     {
         CharPositions.Add(i);
     }
}
```